# Check values of list within a dictionary inside a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have this dictionary (making it simple):

```
tmdbMovie = {'spoken_languages': [{'iso_639_1': 'pt', 'name': 'Português'}]}
```

I'm trying to build an IF clause to check if 'Português' is one valid key for my dict. It's not working as you may expect.. What I've done so far:

```
if 'Português' in [tmdbMovie['spoken_languages'][i]['name'] for i in tmdbMovie['spoken_languages']]:
```

I know I'm missing something.. in this example my list inside dictionary has only one element but it could be more than one.

Error:

```
    if 'Português' in [tmdbMovie['spoken_languages'][i]['name'] for i in tmdbMovie['spoken_languages']]:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict
```

Comment: What is the syntax of `tmdbMovie` here?

Comment: it's all tmdbMovie... that 'info' was a mistake

Comment: Which python version are you using?

Comment: I'm using python3

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for i in tmdbMovie['spoken_languages']` assigns each inner dict in the `'spoken_languages'` list to `i`, so to access its name you'd use `i['name']`. FWIW, I'd use `d` for `dict` there, rather than `i`, which is normally used for a numeric index. Eg,

```
tmdbMovie = {'spoken_languages': [{'iso_639_1': 'pt', 'name': 'Português'}]}

if 'Português' in [d['name'] for d in tmdbMovie['spoken_languages']]:
    print('Yes')
```

**output**

```
Yes
```

A better way is to use `any`:

```
if any(d['name'] == 'Português' for d in tmdbMovie['spoken_languages']):
    print('Yes')
```

`any` stops looking as soon as it's found a match. Also, the `in` operator isn't so efficient on a list, since it has to perform a linear scan over the list until it finds a match. `in` is good for searching a dict or a set. Also, `any` can start searching straight away, your version has to build the whole list of names before `in` can start its scan.

Answer (score 1):

This should fix the issue...

```
if 'Português' in [i['name'] for i in tmdbMovie['spoken_languages']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension or generator expression, as described by @PM2Ring.

However, if you're going to check for the existence of a language often, it's a good idea to create a `set` first and use O(1) lookup available to `set`.

Here's an example:

```
from operator import itemgetter

tmdbMovie = {'spoken_languages': [{'iso_639_1': 'pt', 'name': 'Português'},
                                  {'iso_639_2': 'pt', 'name': 'Français'}]}

language_names = set(map(itemgetter('name'), tmdbMovie['spoken_languages']))

if 'Português' in language_names:
    # do something
```